# Python POST login request

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I'm trying to login using POST method,please help.

```
import urllib2, cookielib
cookie_support= urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar())
opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie_support, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
content = urllib2.urlopen("https://indivinet.ca/api/v1/login",api_key=5f1d5cb35ca1953ecd8f63ac0ac44d3b&location_id=location&username=username&password=password).read()
```

It just says invalid syntax.

Please somebody correct the syntax.

Comment: Please, do always include the full traceback when you post a Python problem, so we don't have to guess as to what line might be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your data value a string; it's not a python expression:

```
content = urllib2.urlopen(
    "https://indivinet.ca/api/v1/login",
    "api_key=5f1d5cb35ca1953ecd8f63ac0ac44d3b&location_id=location&username=username&password=password"
).read()
```